# Python 3.6 Selenium How to find a child node through the reference of a parent node (xPath)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

enter code hereI have two fields by xPath.

- 1st:

  ```
  //*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]
  ```
- 2nd:

  ```
  //*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/input
  ```

I have located and fixed the first div by:

```
main_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]')
```

Is there any way of getting the /input field using the main_field? I mean something like `main_field['input']`. I don't want to use the `find_element_by_xpath` function again if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have located the first field by :

```
main_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]')
```

Now, there is a possibility that the **main_field** may contain one/multiple child nodes. So to get the specific child `<input>` field you can use the reference of the parent node i.e. the **main_field** but you have to invoke `find_element_by_*` again as follows :

```
main_field.find_element_by_xpath('.//input')
```